# Circle pager indicator doesn't look round

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using the [Sherlock pager indicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) and the circles in the pager don't look round enough(I have tried different colors and you can still see they are not round).

[image]

Here is the style I have been using for the `CircleIndicator`

```
<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="unselectedColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="centered">true</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@null</item>
    <item name="pageColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I want to achieve the following result(but with different colors):

[image]

Here is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/brown"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170.00dp"
        android:background="@color/light_blue" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logo_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="..."
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your XML.It seems padding in XML

Comment: @Indiandroid done, but I'm quite sure it is not a problem with the xml layout.

Comment: fix the height of CirclePageIndicator and check it.

Comment: @Indiandroid what is wrong with wrap content?

Comment: I can't say ..i have to make demo and use the library and it is long process....but for testing purpose fixed it's size and  check it.

Comment: did u try removing the margin bottom tag and seeing the if the dot structure is maintained ?

Comment: set everything programmatically ! set stroke black, set fill white !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Add **PADDING**

Have look at the manual example page for circle indicator:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/simple_circles.xml

How does your indicator look, when you just use the basic properties provided in the example?

```
   <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Summarize: ADD PADDING!

Answer (score 4):

add padding to this code snippet

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```